# JavaScript: How to access the second table inside a div using the node of the first table

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this -

```
    <div id="doc">
    <div id="main">
    <table id="vtier#1">
        <tr>
            <td><button> onclick="delVtier(this);return false;" </button></td>
            <td>1.Vtier Name: 
            <select id="vtier" name="vtierN" onchange="populateTable(this,VtierAccountForm); return false;">
        <option>ANY</option>
    </select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<table id="subAccTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <h2>Sub Accounts</h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>action</th>
            <thaccount/></th>
            <th>homeDir</th>
            <th>primaryGroup</th>
        </tr>
</table>
<script>
function populateTable(src,form) {
    var div = src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

        alert(div.childNodes[2].innerHTML);


}
</script>
```

Now inside the populateTable function i have the node of the select tag from the first table. Using this node how can i reach to the node of the second table in my div. I have tried using childNodes[2] but it doesn't work. However childNodes[1] in the alert above correctly prints the innerHTML of the first table. Please help !

Comment: You have some, presumably unrelated, syntax errors in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the variable 'table' points to the first table

```
   var elem = table; 
   while(elem = elem.nextSibling){
      if (elem.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'table'){
         var nextTable = elem;
         break;
      }
    }
```

nextTable will contain the other table

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you access it directly via `document.getElementById("subAccTable")`?

Answer (score 1):

`src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` is actually resolving to your first table. (This is because `src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode` returns the `tbody` element.) You need to traverse one level higher:

```
var div = src.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Although, as others have said, it would be much cleaner to reference the table by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

[`childNodes` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes) returns a list of all DOM nodes, also text (line breaks, etc.). You could use [`children` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.children) to get a lost of element nodes only.

Also the `parentNode` chain does not look good. As your table has an ID, why don't you do:

```
var targetTable = document.getElementById('subAccTable');
```

or, if the table didn't have an ID, you get use `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var targetTable = document.getElementById('main').getElementsByTagName('table')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Element indexes are zero based so `div.childNodes[2]` will result in null or undefined (I can't remember which). Or you could use `document.getElementById('subAccTable')` like others have suggested.